# Labeling the Final Leaves in a Decision Tree Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Using a decision tree classifier to predict the winner of a chess game. In my dataset I have a 'Result' column that gives a 0, 1, or 2 for a win, loss, and draw respectively. How do I ensure that the final leaves of my decision tree classifier are the 'Result' and show its name and value, if this is even possible?

[Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tompaulat/10000-chess-games-with-centipawn-loss)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x = chess.drop(columns = ['Result'])
print(x.head())
y = chess['Result']
print(y.head())

print(x.shape, y.shape)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)

print(x_train.shape, x_test.shape)

#%%
#Decision Tree Classifier

from sklearn import tree 
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5, random_state=0)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_train_pred = clf.predict(x_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)

print(y_pred)

print(metrics.confusion_matrix (y_test, y_pred))
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print(metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average = None))
print(metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average = None))


tree.plot_tree(clf, feature_names = cols, class_names = cols)
plt.savefig('out.pdf')
```

[Decision Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTCqv.png)

I have tried switching my x and y values, adding class_names, dropping different columns, to no avail. I need the final leaves to show their name and value, and that name and value be the 'Result.'

Comment: I don't think I understand your question; what do mean by "[...] ensure that the final leaves of my decision tree classifier are the 'Result'"  ?

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to put it into words. I think an easier question is given my assigned x and y values how do I interpret this decision tree?

Comment: I think you should read some articles/watch some movies regarding a decision tree. THen it should answer your questsion. If it doesn't then I'd suggest you asking a question of the specific thing you aren't understanding (but that would most likely be at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ insted of here)